# Understanding /boot/config file

Tags: linux, configuration, linux-kernel, kernel

In `/boot/config-$kernel_version` I see things like:

```
CONFIG_X86_TSC=y
CONFIG_CAN_TSCAN1=m
```

Now, I thought that `y` stood for `yes`, which means the option is set.
But how about `m`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Y = Module is compiled directly in kernel.
```

Notes: Some drivers should be ready all the time in kernel functionality, without them system can't function like `Unix domain sockets (CONFIG_UNIX)` which should be `Y`

```
N = Don't compile module in kernel. do nothing.
```

Notes: Its your choice whether you want it or not.

```
M = Compile module as loadable module. Kernel will load this module On **Demand**.
```

Notes: M means loadable module which they don't need to stay up all the time, Like `Sound Driver` which you can load when you want to play music. It will make your system more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

It means it is compiled as a kernel Module.

- 'N' - means it is not compiled at all;
- 'Y' - means it is compiled inside the kernel binary file;
- 'M' - means it is compiled as a kernel module.

Comment: So does 'y' mean that it's set directly in the kernel build?